# Bash script to find a sentence pattern

Tags: regex, bash, directory, grep

I'd like to have a script that when there is a text with multiple sentences as a stdin, it would write each sentence on a new line to a stdout. That means that it would only print out those parts that begin with a capital letter and end with only one of the punctuation marks: dot/exclamation/question mark.

Example:

Stdin:

```
This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence! Is this the third sentence? this is not a sentence
```

Stdout:

```
This is the first sentence.
This is the second sentence!
Is this the third sentence?
```

```
while read -r INPUT
do
    if [[ "$SENFLAG" == "1" ]]
    then
        echo "$INPUT" | grep -o '[[:alpha:]][^ ]*[A-Z][^ ]*' 
    fi
done
```

I tried working with grep, but I am not sure how to advance further.

Comment: Blatant self promotion of a work in progress: https://github.com/shawnw/unicode-text-utils -- the `usplit` program can break up input text by sentences according to Unicode break rules, one per line. Not quite exactly what you're looking for, but close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Eo '[A-Z][^.!?]*[.!?]' input_file
```

Comment: I would remove the dot after `[A-Z]` and, maybe, the final space.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help! I tried using the code, but it unfortunately doesn't work, it returns all the sentences on one line.

Comment: @George0541 Sorry the code was changed. Reverted to original

Comment: Thank you! One more question, if you don't mind. Would you know how to instead of [A-Z], to use `[[:alpha:]]`, so that not only would it accept English alphabet, but also other accents? For example German umlauts, even as the first letter? I only managed to make it work so that it can read other alphabet types in the middle of stdin, but not at the beginning. For example word `Über.`.

Comment: @George0541 Do you mean `grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]][^.!?]*[.!?]'`?

Comment: @HatLess Yes, exactly, but unfortunately with this approach, stdin like `über.` (with a small letter) also works, and I can't get it to make it work only with a beginning capital letter.

Comment: @George0541 Could you provide an example of the data?

Comment: @HatLess Nevermind, I solved it with this simple solution `grep -Eo '([[:upper:]][[:alpha:]][^.!?]*[.!?])'`. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach via `sed`. Its not a short command but better to understand I think.

```
sed -e 's/\![[:space:]]/\!\n/g' \
-e 's/\?[[:space:]]/\?\n/g' \
-e 's/\.[[:space:]]/\.\n/g' | \
grep -v '^[[:lower:]]'
This is the first sentence.
This is the second sentence!
Is this the third sentence?
```

Explanation:

First thee `set` commands looking for that punctuation mark followed by white space `\![[:space:]]` and replace them with that same punctuation mark and a new line `\!\n`.
At last `grep` is looking through all lines and remove the ones starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank you for the command and explanation! I have one question, though. I was testing the code, and it works great, but I noticed that it also returns the result even if the sentence begins with a capital letter, but ends without any punctuation mark. So for example: `This is not a sentence` also returns the same. Is it possible to make it so that it returns only the sentence that ends only with one of those punctuation marks? Thanks.

Comment: @George0541 you can add one more command at the end, like `| grep '[[:punct:]]$'`or `| grep '[.!?]$'`.